# Rails 6 testing - "Could not find table" error on table that was previously dropped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to write some test for my rails app.  On the first line of the definition for my very first test, rails throws this unhelpful error:

```
Error:
LabStationTest#test_prioritize_students_basic:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'equipment'
```

`equipment` was a table that I deleted in a previous migration.  I have no more references to it in my code, and have since then run commands like `rails db:drop`, `rails db:migrate`, `rails db:reset`, and `rails db:test:prepare` multiple times to no avail.

I tried searching project-wide for the word "equipment", and I did find a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "equipment"` statement left over in `structure.sql` for some reason.  I'm not sure if that's relevant or how to safely delete it, and I couldn't find any other references to that term.

Rails is great but it absolutely drives me nuts how the codegen scatters hidden references all over the place.  Anyone know what I should do next?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this, I discovered outdated models left over in `test/fixtures` - this seems to be the culprit.

Errors like this are my biggest frustration with Rails, they cast doubt on the "convention over configuration" paradigm for me.  It wouldn't be half as bad if they at least included a stack trace with the error messages, but even with the `-v` flag they tend to provide little useful information

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes here looking for an answer, I got more info when running

```bash
rails db:fixtures:load
```